# Don't know how to optimize the code with Cython

Tags: python, optimization, cython, cythonize

I'm new on trying to optimize with cython and I need some help because I know I can optimize more but I don't know how.

Firstly what I did was declare the variables in C, however a lot of them are objects, and I don't know how to declare that.

Then I have the class, in the HTML I can see every time the code wants to get an object of the class it is slow, so I wanna optimize that too, and I don't know how to do it :(

```
import math
import random

def class City:
  def __init__(self, city_name='NoName', posx=0, posy=0):
    self.name = city_name
    self.x = posx
    self.y = posy

def distance_between_cities( object C1, object C2 ):
    """Compute distance between two cities"""
    dx = C1.x - C2.x
    dy = C1.y - C2.y
    return math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy )

def read_cities_from_file ( str filename ):
    """Read list of Cities from text file"""
    cdef list Cities= [] # List of Empty Cities
    cdef list R = []
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            R= line.split()
            Cities.append ( City( R[0], float(R[1]), float(R[2]) ) )
    return Cities

def path_distance( object Cities ):
    """Compute total distance of the path traversing all cities in order"""
    cdef int i = 0
    cdef double D = 0
    for i in range( len(Cities) ):
        D = D + distance_between_cities ( Cities[i],
                                          Cities[i+1 if i+1<len(Cities) else 0])
    return D

cdef int closerCity( object City, object Cities ):
    """Compute position of the city C in the list of Cities that is closer to City"""
    cdef float minDist = 2*1000*1000
    cdef int minIndex= 0
    cdef int i = 0
    cdef double dx = 0
    cdef double dy = 0
    cdef double dist = 0
    for i in range(len(Cities)):
        c = Cities[i]
        dx = City.x - c.x
        dy = City.y - c.y
        dist = dx*dx + dy*dy
        if dist < minDist:
            minDist = dist
            minIndex= i
    return minIndex

def GoodPath( object Cities ):
    """Generate a path with small total distance using greedy algorithm"""
    cdef list NotVisited = []
    cdef int len_C = len(Cities)
    cdef int i = 0
    for i in range(len_C):
      NotVisited.append(Cities[i])
    Path= [ Cities[0] ] # Start path with first city
    del NotVisited[0]
    while len(NotVisited) > 0:
        pos = closerCity( Path[-1], NotVisited )
        Path.append( NotVisited[pos] )
        del NotVisited[pos]
    return Path

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import argparse as arg
  parser = arg.ArgumentParser(prog='ARGUMENTS', usage='%(prog)s [options]')
  parser.add_argument("input",  type=str, help="File containing list of Cities")
  args = parser.parse_args()
  
  ListOfCities= read_cities_from_file ( str(args.input) )
  GoodList    = GoodPath( ListOfCities )
  print ( "Initial Distance =", path_distance( ListOfCities ),
          "  Good Distance =",  path_distance( GoodList) )
```

This is what I get from the HTML when I cythonize:
[Part 1 of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rCDk.png)
[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7xkg.png)

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of your algorithm is **`O(n^2)`** (with `n` the number of cities). Indeed, you walk through all the cities and for each city you iterate over most of the cities again (`O(n)` cities). Note also that item deletion is algo performed in `O(n)` time. The result can be computed with a more efficient **`O(n log n)`** algorithm:

You can build a [K-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) structure, or more specifically a [Quad-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) structure in `O(n log n)` time and then find the closest city of any other city in `O(log n)` time with this structure. Additionally, it is better to change the type of `NotVisited` to a **`set`** rather than a `list` to avoid a slow list item deletion.

Apart from that, I advise you to replace `object`-typed variables with **lower-level types** (eg. arrays or tuples of double/int) so that Cython can generate a faster C code.

Note that your method will often not find the overall shortest path and may not even find a quite small path. There are [better algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm), but they are more expensive.